# Clockworkmod recovery, unable to backup the /data partition

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

My device is a rooted Samsung Galaxy S4 mini (serranoltexx) with CWM 6.0.4.6 recovery.
When I try to take a nandroid backup of my device it gives me the this error:

> error while making backup of /data!

Flashing a ROM works fine, is this a permission issue?

Comment: Is `/data` successfully mounted when you enter recovery? Check if you can access `/data` in another way (e.g. adb). If you can then the backup script is broken.

Comment: Well, my recovery supports neither adb or console line. I forgot to mention that it is a `CWM-based` Recovery. TWRP doensn't officially support my device and my device was shipped to me with this recovery installed.

Comment: AFAIK `cwm` should support `adb` (at least it did on my phone). Is there any real log file that gives the error a bit more clear then just `there was an error `?